# Trigger to insert percentage value in a table based on the values of two different fields

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a table 'attendance' having 3 fields 'class_total','class_attended' and 'attendance_percent'.
I want to insert/update the value of 'attendance_percent' whenever values are inserted/updated in the fields 'class_total' and 'class_attended' by (class_attended/class_total)*100.
For this I am using the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER percent_update
BEFORE INSERT ON attendance
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.attendance_percent =(attendance.class_attended/attendance.class_total)*100 ;
```

But its not working.

Comment: If attendance_percent is calculated from another fields, you can calculate this value on the fly in SELECT statement.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "not working"?  Are you getting errors, no data inserted, the wrong data inserted, etc, etc?  Examples help :)

Comment: The trigger query is ok.But after that when i try to insert values in the table:

INSERT INTO attendance(class_total,class_attended)
VALUES(5,4);
Mysql is giving error 1109(42S02):Unknown table 'attendance' in field list.
If i delete the trigger attendance_update, the insertion query is working fine.

Comment: Why would you use a trigger to do that ? Given that the percentage is always the attendance / total, why don't you have the percentage as a computed column (and do away with the complexity of having a trigger) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a NEW clause instead of table name -

```
...
SET NEW.attendance_percent = (NEW.class_attended/NEW.class_total)
...
```